# Scroll view auto scrolls or moves up for each new line entered in the Edittext

Tags: android

I have scrollview as a 1st parent layout and then linear layout as its child and then list of different views like spinner edittext textview etc inside the linear layout. The height of the edittext is fixed to some random value. The problem is when i type more data into edittext as the number of lines increases scrollview auto scrolls and the views are moved up whenever a new line is added into edittext. At one point edittext is not visible at all as it is scrolled up beyond the toolbar and we cannot see what data we are typing.

I need views to remain in the same position or stop autoscroll of scrollview when a new line is added in the edittext.

Below are screenshots

[As new lines are inserted views are moved up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myPJB.png).

[Now the edittext has moved completely up and not visible at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLYZ7.png)

Comment: You have to post code

Comment: @Raghavendra i have created child views programmatically only scrollview and linear layout are in xml layout.